# Copying and pasting an entire tex file. Why doesn't the bibliography work?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker

Suppose I have a tex file (a) with a bib file (b). Suppose then I open a blank tex file, and copy and paste the entire tex file (a). I call this new tex file (c). Then I rename the bib file and call it (d). I refer to file (d) in my new tex file (c). When I run and compile the new file (c), why don't the citations appear in the text, only question marks instead?

I have no idea how to overcome this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you compile with BibTeX ([Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864))? Is 'd' in the same folder as 'c'?

Comment: BTW: You say you see only question marks, this makes me think you are not actually using `biblatex`, but standard BibTeX (maybe `natbib`) with its `.bst` files. If that is the case, please consider re-tagging your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an experienced tex user. I am using Texmaker, and calling my bibliography files with a .bib ending. Yes, 'd' and 'c' are in the same folder. Only question marks appear in the pdf output, while the bibliography list itself is missing completely. @moewe

Comment: Have a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), please. You will have to run BibTeX.

Comment: ok, when I compile, the following error comes up: "The top-level auxiliary file: revision.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file revision.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file revision.aux " The "revision" is the file (c). @moewe

Comment: Thanks, it's fine - I figured out what the error was. @moewe

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: It was surely the good old "you shall compile twice !"